# Tracking changes using git during code review (stash vs. branch)

Tags: git, git-branch, git-stash

In the interest of keeping code reviews small and concise, I've submitted a smaller code review than a full feature.  It is the cleanup before a larger change, but to avoid cluttering up the final review with the cleanup, I've made this review.

My later work will build on this currently active review, and there will be changes that I need to make as a result of the review.  However, I would also like to continue working on the final feature while this code is in review.

How I can properly track my development on the feature while still remaining able to make changes for code review.

Current scenario:

```
master -x-x-x---x---|
feature      \-x-x-x| code review
```

Future scenario (branching)

```
master -x-x-x---x---|
feature      \-x-x-x|-x--x--|
  feature2          \x--x--x| code review complete (merge)
```

Future scenario (stash)

```
master -x-x-x---x---|
feature      \-x-x-x|-x--x--| code review complete (merge)
  work on feature branch, stash changes if needed to make code review updates
```

I think the branch model makes more sense, but creating another branch with the same name and same purpose seems to violate some sense of "git propriety"

Comment: If it's really just a continuation of work on the same feature, I would just create a branch called `feature-review` and submit that for code review, and then continue working and committing on the `feature` branch.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think branching is the right approach; you might just want good branch names, and instead of making a new branch for your work, use the new branch to "freeze" a snapshot of the code for the code review.

Say your repository look like this when you want to submit `feature` for code review.

```
* -- * -- * -- * -- * -- * -- *  master
      \
       * -- * -- * -- * feature, HEAD
```

Just create a new branch called (`cr/feature`), where `cr` is short for (you guessed it) "code review".

```
git branch cr/feature
```

Now your current branch head has two branches referring to it.

```
* -- * -- * -- * -- * -- * -- *  master
      \
       * -- * -- * -- * feature, cr/feature, HEAD
```

As you continue work on feature, you don't affect the code undergoing code review.

```
* -- * -- * -- * -- * -- * -- *  master
      \
       * -- * -- * -- * -- * -- * -- * feature, HEAD
                      |
                    cr/feature
```

Once the code review is complete, does the reviewed code get merged into `master`?

```
git checkout master
git merge cr/feature
git branch -d cr/feature  # Optional


* -- * -- * -- * -- * -- * -- * -- *  master
      \                           /
       *   --   *   --   *  --   * -- * -- * -- * feature, HEAD
                                 |
                             cr/feature (if not deleted)
```

This way, the code reviewer(s) never see your continued work on `feature` until you submit it for code view by explicitly creating a branch for them to look at.

If there are updates needed to the reviewed code, you can add those to the `cr/feature` branch:

```
* -- * -- * -- * -- * -- * -- *  master
      \
       * -- * -- * -- * -- * -- * -- * feature, HEAD
                      \
                       * -- * cr/feature
```

and either merge `cr/feature` back into `feature`

```
* -- * -- * -- * -- * -- * -- *  master
      \
       * -- * -- * -- * -- * -- * -- * -- * feature, HEAD
                      \                  /
                       *      -----     * cr/feature
```

or rebase `feature` on top of the code review branch

```
* -- * -- * -- * -- * -- * -- *  master
      \
       * -- * -- * -- *       * -- * -- * feature, HEAD
                      \      /
                       * -- *  cr/feature
```

Answer (score 1):

What I ended up doing was as chepner and larsks suggested:

I had already made some changes, so I needed to stash what I'd done first.  On branch `feature`.

```
git stash
```

Then created the code review branch, which has only what I had already submitted to the review.

```
git checkout -b feature-cr
```

Finally, put my stashed changes back onto my feature branch

```
git checkout feature
git stash pop
git commit -am "Some descriptive commit message"
```